# Get closest day in future in a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have date list in yyyy/mm/dd:

```
2020/06/10
2020/06/18
2020/07/17
```

and given date

```
2020/06/10
```

I want to find closest day in future from the given date in LINQ (expected result: 2020/06/18).

Comment: " earliest full day to given date " could you please explain a little more? do you mean the closest day in future from the given date? and what is a full day?

Comment: Yes, the closest day in future from list, by saying full day I highlight that I want 2020/06/18 not 2020/06/10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to find the closest date in future then you can filter out all earlier dates (including the same date), order it and then take the first value:

```
List<DateTime> allDates = new List<System.DateTime>()
{
    new DateTime(2020, 06, 10),
    new DateTime(2020, 06, 18),
    new DateTime(2020, 07, 17),
};

DateTime givenDate = new DateTime(2020, 06, 10);

DateTime closestDateInFuture = allDates.Where(x => x > givenDate).OrderBy(x=> x).First();
Console.WriteLine(closestDateInFuture);
```

Output:

> 18.06.2020 00:00:00

Another suggestion by [@Johnathan Barclay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8126362/johnathan-barclay) is to use the `Min` method, which yields the same result:

```
DateTime closestDateInFuture = allDates.Where(x => x > givenDate).Min()
```

Comment: Or even `allDates.Where(x => x > givenDate).Min()`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay included it into my answer. If you decide to write your own answer, I will remove it again :)

Comment: I don't think it warrants a separate answer :)